# How to pass Imagemagick montage output and image properties to the convert command without using any temporary files?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-montage

I have a set of images, and I can use the Imagemagick `montage` command on them to produce a montage image file with transparent background (let's call this `fgimg`). Now I have another existing image (let's call this `bgimg`) that I'd like to use (after some special processing with the `convert` command) as the background for `fgimg`, which can be achieved within the same `convert` command. At this point it seems trivial to avoid writing the temporary `fgimg` to disk, simply by piping the standard output of `montage` to the standard input of `convert`.

My problem is that the special processing I'm applying to `bgimg` will require some knowledge of the image properties of `fgimg` (e.g., resizing `bgimg` to have the same size as `fgimg`), which I don't know in advance. **How can this information be retrieved and used in the `convert` command?**

Note: I'm using Imagemagick version 6.9.7-4 on Linux.

---

I'll include some commands below to further illustrate the problem in detail.

The following command produces the montage image `fgimg` from a set of input images. The output is in the 'special' `miff` format (which seems best for temporary output to be worked on later), and has transparent background so that the actual background can be applied later. Most of the other options here are not important, but the point is that the output size (dimensions) cannot be determined in advance.

```
montage input_*.jpg -tile 5x -border 2 -geometry '200x200>+20+20' \
  -gravity center -set label '%f\n%G' -background none -fill white \
  -title 'Sample Title' miff:fgimg
```

Next, I have another input image `bgimg.jpg`. I want to perform some processing on it before using it as background to `fgimg`. The processing can be quite complex in general, but in this example, I want to:

1. resize `bgimg.jpg` to fit inside the dimensions of `fgimg` without any cropping;
2. apply a fade-to-black effect around the edges;
3. make it the same size as `fgimg`, with a black background;
4. combine this with `fgimg` to produce the final output.

Notice that I need the size of `fgimg` in two places. I can first extract this into a shell variable:

```
size=$(identify -format '%G' miff:fgimg)
```

Then I can do all the steps above in one `convert` command (note that `$size` is used twice):

```
convert "bgimg.jpg[$size]" -gravity center \
  \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100% -bordercolor black \
  -shave 20 -border 20 -blur 0x20 \) -compose multiply -composite \
  -background black -compose copy -extent $size \
  miff:fgimg -compose over -composite final_out.jpg
```

Now here is the problem: **I want to avoid writing the temporary file `fgimg` to disk.**

I could replace `miff:fgimg` with `miff:-` in both the `montage` and `convert` commands and then just pipe one to the other: `montage ... | convert ...`. But how do I deal with the `$size`?

I tried to use file descriptors (`miff:fd:3`) but this does not seem to work, which is confirmed by the comments to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/correct-syntax-for-use-of-file-descriptors-with-imagemagick).

Is there a way to do this (in Imagemagick v6) without creating a temporary file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example command uses ImageMagick v6 on a bash shell. Instead of "montage" it starts by using "convert" to create a "logo:", one of IM's built-in sample images, then pipes it out as a MIFF and into the "convert" command that follows. You can pipe the output of "montage" just as easily. And it uses another IM built-in image "rose:" as your "bgimg.jpg"...

```
convert logo: miff:- | convert - rose: \
   +distort SRT "%[fx:t?min(u.w/v.w,u.h/v.h):1] 0" \
   -shave 1 +repage -gravity center -bordercolor black \
   \( -clone 1 -fill white -colorize 100 -shave 6 -border 6 \
      -blur 0x6 -clone 1 -compose multiply -composite \) -delete 1 \
   \( -clone 0 -alpha off -fill black -colorize 100 \
      -clone 1 -compose over -composite \) -delete 1 \
   +swap -composite final_out.jpg
```

That reads the piped image "-" and the background image "rose:".

Then it uses "+distort" with an FX expression to scale "rose:" to the maximum dimensions that still fit within the original piped input image. That operation adds a pixel all around so we use "-shave 1" to get rid of that.

Next inside parentheses it clones that re-scaled background image, makes an edge blur mask, and composites them to make the fade-to-black edge on the background image. Right after the parentheses it deletes the non-edged background image.

In the next parentheses it clones the input image, makes it black, clones the modified background image, and composites it centered over the black one. Again the non-extended background image is discarded after the parentheses with "-delete 1".

Finally the modified background and the input image are put in the proper order with "+swap" and composited for the final output. Run this command without the last "-composite" to see the two images that result from the prior parts of the command.

Both the main input image and background image can be any size, any dimensions, and any aspect ratio. This works for me on v6.8.9 on a bash shell. It should work on any ImageMagick newer. It should work on Windows by removing all the backslashes that escape parentheses and changing the continued-line backslashes "\" to carets "^".

EDITED TO ADD:

You can use that FX expression to find the scaling amount, save it as a variable, then isolate the background image inside parentheses and use that variable to do the scaling and shaving there. That way it only affects the background image. There may be a rounding error with that, but the main image, which determines the exact final output dimensions, will be unaffected. Note the difference in the first few lines of this command...

```
convert logo: miff:- | convert - rose: \
   -set option:v1 "%[fx:min(u.w/v.w,u.h/v.h)]" \
   \( -clone 1 +distort SRT "%[v1] 0" -shave 1 \) -delete 1 \
   +repage -gravity center -bordercolor black \
   \( -clone 1 -fill white -colorize 100 -shave 6 -border 6 \
      -blur 0x6 -clone 1 -compose multiply -composite \) -delete 1 \
   \( -clone 0 -alpha off -fill black -colorize 100 \
      -clone 1 -compose over -composite \) -delete 1 \
   +swap final_out.jpg
```

Comment: This works very well for me. Using `distort SRT` with `fx` expression to resize is nice. But I'm surprised to find that, more generally, supplying `"1 0"` as arguments to `distort SRT` (like it was done here for the image "logo:") does not actually preserve the size. I tested this on a few images: it sometimes adds 2 pixels in each dimension, but other times 3. So the `-shave 1` here is perfect if it is 2 pixels in both dimensions, but in some cases we'd have half a pixel extra along some of the edges, is that right? It does not matter for me here, but might do for others more generally.

Comment: I added another example command above that shows how to modify the command to set and apply a variable to resolve some of that concern.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can set global variables like that. This could be quite useful in general, but I guess the trick is to know which options support escapes expansion, e.g., `+distort SRT` expands escapes, but `-resize` and `-distort Resize` apparently do not.

Comment: The use of FX expressions is quite limited with ImageMagick v6, but they can be used almost anywhere in IMv7 commands.